# Can i call the get method in django class based views from the post method

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

In my django app's `views.py` i have a class based view `Profile(View)` which has two methods `get(self, request)` and `post(self, request)`. So when a post request is send to this view, when the input passes a test, i want to go invoke the `get()` method which will return the template with updated data. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, just try it, it works.

Comment: This is actually *not* a good idea, since if the user refreshes the browser, the POST request will be done a *second* time. Usually it is POST-REDIRECT-GET: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: do i `return self.get(request)` or just `self.get()` ?

Comment: It's not a **good** idea

Comment: so should i`redirect('/to/view's/get/url')` ?

Comment: @kingraphaII: `return redirect(..)`, and probably better to use view resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, this is of course perfectly possible and as simple as `return self.get(request, **kwargs)` BUT you very certainly DONT want to do that, as it will break the expectations of POST vs GET. The canonical navigation pattern is that a sucessful POST should be followed by a redirect, and is known as [the "post-redirect-get" pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). Note that you can use sessions (directly or with the `messages` framework) if you want to pass some state (outside database state) from the POST to the GET.